# My Ajax Post response code is not working?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Every time the error message is alerted.I dont know if my hr.status is   wrong or hr.ready is wrong  or there is some other error.I cant quite figure what is the problem with this code I have spent Hours Modifying it but to no avail!
I am taking an input through html and sending it to php through ajax POST.Php is supposed to send the response text back.But it is not showing rather it is saying there is some error in my onreadystate function.

Javascript Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <script>
            function ajax_get_json(){
            var results = document.getElementById("results");
            var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var namee=document.getElementById("nam").value;
            var nams="fn="+namee;
            hr.open("POST", "marks.php", true);
            hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = data;
            else
                    {alert("Error");}
            }
            }
            hr.send(nams);
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "processing...";

            }
            </script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <form>
            Name:<input type="text" id="nam" name="sname"><br><!--My input-->
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="ajax_get_json();">
            </form>
            <div id="results"></div>
            </body>
            </html>
Every time the error message is alerted.I dont know if my hr.status is   wrong or hr.ready is wrong  or there is some other error.I cant quite figure what is the problem with this code I have spent Hours Modifying it but to no avail!!
```

PHP CODE

```
   <?php
    $aa=$_POST['fn'];
    echo $aa;

    ?>
```

Comment: There is a closing curly brace missing ( or is it) after document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = data;

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a } before the else. You also have have an extra } above hr.send.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = data;
            }
            else
            {
                  alert("Error");
            }
            }
            hr.send(nams);
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "processing...";

            }
```

Just add "}" Before else and remove "} after else

Comment: hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status==200) {
var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);

document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = data;}
else
  {alert("Error");}

}
hr.send(nams);
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "processing...";

Comment: But now it only shows processing.... and then displays the error messaga.